# How to parse dictionary syntaxed string to dictionary object

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a file syntaxed in a way that ressembles a Dictionary as follows:

```
{YEARS:5}
{GROUPS:[1,2]}
{SAVE_FILE:{USE:1,NAME:CustomCalendar.ics}}
{SAVE_ONLINE:{USE:1,NAME:Custom Calendar,EMAIL:an.email@something.com,PASSWORD:AcompLExP@ssw0rd}}
{COURSES:[BTC,CIT,CQN,OSA,PRJCQN,PRJIOT,PILS,SPO,SHS1]}
```

I would like to find a way to parse each individual line into a dictionary as it is written. The difficulty I have is that some of these lines contain a dictionary as their value.

I am capable of taking the single lines and converting them to actual dictionaries but I am having an issue when working with the other lines.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def get_config(filename=):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as config:
        years = config.read().split()[0]
        print(parse_line(years))

def parse_line(input_line):
    input_line = input_line.strip("{}")
    input_line = input_line.split(":")
    return {input_line[i]: input_line[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(input_line), 2)}
```

If at all possible, I'd love to be able to deal with any line within a single function and hopefully deal with more than two nested dictionaries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you fix whatever is creating these to use a standard format like JSON? Writing an ad hoc parser yourself is not going to be robust.

Comment: That could be a good idea, however this file will usually be manually created and edited and I'm not sure JSON is very user-friendly... But if it's required then I may have to

Comment: Then use some other standard configuration file format, you can probably find a library already written to parse it. E.g. the syntax used in named.conf.

Comment: JSON **is** user-friendly. Imagine, you can store stuff in a standardized way and use a bunch of libraries to parse those file. That'd be great!

Comment: What I meant by user-friendly is the visual representation which isn't as simple to understand as single lines in a text file

Comment: This undoubtedly is a question of taste. IMHO, JSON offers a quite readable syntax, especially if lines get longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file would contain valid JSON format, it would be an easy task to read the file and convert your data structures to dictionaries.

To give an example, consider having the following line of text in a file `text.txt`:

```
{"SAVE_ONLINE":{"USE":1,"NAME":"Custom Calendar","EMAIL":"an.email@something.com","PASSWORD":"AcompLExP@ssw0rd"}}
```

Please note, that the only difference are the quotes `"` around strings.

You can easily parse the line to a dictionary structure with:

```
import json

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
```

#### Output

```
print(d)
# {'SAVE_ONLINE': {'USE': 1, 'NAME': 'Custom Calendar', 'EMAIL': 'an.email@something.com', 'PASSWORD': 'AcompLExP@ssw0rd'}}
```